# azure-fuctions-core-tools@4を使用したローカルデバッグ(python)時、ブレークポイントにヒットしない

Tags: python, python3, azure

VisualStudioCodeを用い、AzureFunctions関数(python)開発を行なっております。

azure-fuctions-core-tools@4（msi）を使用したローカルデバッグ(python)について、デバッグ実行したとき、ブレークポイントにヒットしてくれず、正常終了する挙動です。ブレークポイントにヒットしてくれるように実行するための解決策あればご教授いただきたいです。

Python 3.9.3

tasks.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "func",
      "label": "func: host start",
      "command": "host start",
      "problemMatcher": "$func-python-watch",
      "isBackground": true,
      "dependsOn": "pip install (functions)"
    },
    {
      "label": "pip install (functions)",
      "type": "shell",
      "osx": {
        "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
      },
      "windows": {
        "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}\\Scripts\\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
      },
      "linux": {
        "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
      },
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ]
}
```

launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9091,
      "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
    }
  ]
}
```